# Talend tool - "A palette is not available"

Tags: talend

I am using Talend ETL tool .

But now I got notification "A palette is not available" , Now I can't do anything in this tool. How can I resolved this ? please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to open a demo job to see the palette.

[Click here to know more](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=15818)